# How to get Token from authenticate method with parameters and use it into other API's headers

Tags: c#, restsharp, specflow

this is my method to authentificate and **get token** in my TokenClass:

```
public static String SeconnecterEtGetToken(String login, String pwd)
{
    restRequest = new RestRequest(loginUrl, Method.GET);
    restRequest.AddHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic ZRZEFSFCSDFSFSDFSDS");
    restRequest.AddParameter("username", login);
    restRequest.AddParameter("password", pwd);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(restRequest);
    string resp = response.Content;
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
    string mytoken = jObject.GetValue("access_token").ToString();
    return mytoken;
}
```

Then i have to use this "mytoken" in to header of all other API exemple :

```
restRequest.AddParameter("Authorization", string.Format( "Bearer" + TokenClass.SeconnecterEtGetToken(login,pwd)), ParameterType.HttpHeader);
```

It's dosent work because i dont have **"login" and "pwd"** in all API requests

Any ideas please ?

Comment: How does this relate to [tag:specflow]? Do you need to use this token in other step definitions? If so, please add some more code to include the step definition where you initially get the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call SeconnecterEtGetToken method and check if it returns a token or not and then use it in the header of the request, but first, you need to check Username and Password

Comment: this is the problem, i want to use directly the token

Comment: I use a variable to get my token=>" ScenarioContext.Current["mytoken"] = mytoken; " and i call it in the other methods =>" string token = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<String>("mytoken");"